# android button same height as textview

Tags: android, user-interface, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am struggling creating the UI for a list item which should look like this:[image]

I am trying to build a similar layout for my list items like in the picture above. However, I am stuck, because I don't exactly know, how to nest the views so the sell-buttons has the same height as both textviews.

If I use the RelativeLayout than I cannot use the layout_weight attribute anymore which position the views evenly horizontally on the screen.

However, if I use the LinearLayout than I cannot use the relative-attributes like alignTop and so on. I am trying to nest the views in a way so I can achieve this, however I am failing so far... (sry for my poor english skills)

This is what I have so far, however I still cannot get the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Google Pixel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/productname"
            tools:text="699$" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            tools:text="Quantity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/quantity_textview"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            tools:text="31" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        tools:text="SELL"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for your Button? This will mke the Button's height equal to the parent height.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean...M< problem is that the top height and bottom height should match the height of the textview...like in the picture the top border of the button matches the top border of the porduct name (google pixel) and the bottom border of the button matches the bottom border of the second text view which is the price

Comment: Given that you have a custom row, which is a layout (no matter which one, actually). Making your button as tall as the row solves your issue. That's because the two TextViews are obviously aligned one to the top border and the other one to the bottom border of the row. Or, at least, this is how I would make it. It's really a no-brainer

Comment: I have edited my question...maybe I am thinking too complicated..If I make visible the borders of the views than they have the same height, however the button top/bottom border do not match the height of the textviews..it is not a straight line

Comment: Mind that nesting layouts is bad for performances. A RelativeLayout would lead to faster runs.

Comment: I have edited my question again  (avoided the nested layouts for a better performance)...however, i still cannot get my desired result...I dont know how to align the bottom/top borders of the button with the textviews, like shown in the first picture

Comment: Then, reread my comments above. It's really easy to do.

Comment: I really appreciate for you taking your time and giving me some hints, however I really don't know how to solve this...I tried know to group the textviews in a nested layout and set a fixed height and than set the same height for my button...I edited my question to be more clear what I am trying to do...I really think this is not as easy solved as you think...or am I missing something? I really don't get your solution

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. Probably, a deep knowledge of RelativeLayouts.

Comment: Well, that's very helpful....thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html). This will allow you to set the top of the button to be constrained to the top of first text view, the bottom of the button to be constrained to the bottom of the second text view, and maintain the even distribution left to right with a horizontal chain.

Here's a an example I just threw together for funsies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        tools:text="Google Pixel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        tools:text="6995" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Quantity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        tools:text="31" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        tools:text="Sell" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This gives you this layout in the preview:

[image: Sample Layout]

And this is what the preview looks like showing the constraints. You can see the button being constrained to the two views (dashed lines), and the chain across the "Google Pixel" label, the "Quantity" label, and the button that keeps everything evenly distributed.

[image: Sample Layout Showing Constraints]

Note that if you want the button to be smaller to shrink down to match the bottom of the second text view, you have to set the button's minHeight attribute to 0. You'll probably also have to replace the default background of the button if you want pixel-perfect alignment of the top and bottom as the default background drawable has some built-in padding.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Frame Layout, with it you will be able to align your views according to your need.
Or you can use a listview with a custom adapter for creating this kind of view. You can refer to this link

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Thx, but that's not the point..I know how to use a custom adapter and so on....Did u read my question?

Comment: I've read ur question...if u know how to create a custom adapter then i don't think there is any problem in creating a button with same height as textview. you just have to make the height to match it's parent view

Comment: Thx for your fast reply, however I am still stuck..I have edited my question